# dplyr::if_else changes datetime (POSIXct) values

Tags: r, dplyr, posixct

I'm working with a dataset that has a lot of timestamps. There are some invalid timestamps which I try to identify and set to NA. Because `if_else()` forces me to have the same data type in both arms, I'm using `as.POSIXct(NA)` to encode such missing values.

Interestingly, the results differ when I invert the test (and change the `true` and `false` argument) in `if_else()`.

Here is some code to illustrate my problems:

```
x <- tibble(
  A = parse_datetime("2020-08-18 19:00"),
  B = if_else(TRUE,               A, as.POSIXct(NA)),
  C = if_else(FALSE, as.POSIXct(NA),              A)
)

> x
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  A                   B                   C                  
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2020-08-18 19:00:00 2020-08-18 19:00:00 2020-08-18 21:00:00
```

Any idea, why C is two hours later?

### Follow-up:

Based on the great answers below, I think a more readable solution should perhaps generate a missing datetime object with `parse_datetime(NA_character_)` and use this in the code instead of `as.POSIXct()`.

```
R> NA_datetime_ <- parse_datetime(NA_character_)

R> x <- tibble(
  A = parse_datetime("2020-08-18 19:00"),
  B = if_else(TRUE,             A, NA_datetime_),
  C = if_else(FALSE, NA_datetime_,            A)
)

R> map(x, lubridate::tz)
$A
[1] "UTC"

$B
[1] "UTC"

$C
[1] "UTC"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At First, you need to know that `parse_datetime()` returns a date-time object with an `tzone` attribute default to `UTC`. You can use `lubridate::tz(x$A)` and `attributes(x$A)` to check it.

From the document of `if_else()`, it said the `true` and `false` arguments must be the same type. *All other attributes are taken from `true`*. Hence, in part `C` of your tibble:

```
C = if_else(FALSE, as.POSIXct(NA), A)
```

`as.POSIXct(NA)` doesn't have a `tzone` attribute, so `A`'s `tzone` is dropped and reset to the time zone of your region. Actually, `C` is ***not*** two hours later. *The three columns have equal time but unequal time zones.* To fix it, you can adjust `as.POSIXct(NA)` to own a `tzone` attribute, i.e. replace it with

```
as.POSIXct(NA_character_, tz = "UTC")
```

***Note:*** *You must use `NA_character_` instead of `NA` because the `tz` argument in `as.POSIXct()` only works on character objects.*

---

Finally, revise your code as

```
x <- tibble(
  A = parse_datetime("2020-08-18 19:00"),
  B = if_else(TRUE, A, as.POSIXct(NA_character_, tz = "UTC")),
  C = if_else(FALSE, as.POSIXct(NA_character_, tz = "UTC"), A)
)

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#   A                   B                   C                  
#   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1 2020-08-18 19:00:00 2020-08-18 19:00:00 2020-08-18 19:00:00
```

Remember to check their time zones.

```
R > lubridate::tz(x$A)
[1] "UTC"
R > lubridate::tz(x$B)
[1] "UTC"
R > lubridate::tz(x$C)
[1] "UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks for the many details. I think I understand the issue but still find this a quite problematic behaviour. I guess a warning should be generated when attributes are changed by if_else.
For me, a more transparent solution would be to use `parse_datetime(NA_character)` instead of `as.POSIXct(NA_character, tz = "UTC")` to generate missing values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a timezone problem :

```
lubridate::tz(x$A)
[1] "UTC"
lubridate::tz(x$B)
[1] "UTC"
lubridate::tz(x$C)
[1] ""
```

This is due to the way `if_else <- function (test, yes, no)`  works : it uses the attributes of the `yes` argument which for C is `NA`.

Comment: And you can fix it by doing `if_else(FALSE, as.POSIXct(NA), as.POSIXct(as.character(A)))`. Does seem like a bug though.

Comment: @AllanCameron your method makes the three time look equal, but actually the third time zone are different.

Comment: @Waldi: I think this is even another bug: if_else does not only change the value of A when copying it into C, it also drops the timezone attribute. Do you think of this as a feature or should I try and issue a bug report to the dplyr people?

Comment: @AxelFacius it does the same to data.table::fifelse. It doesn't seem to be a problem of dplyr::if_else only.

Comment: @Alex Facius, see answer from Darren Tsai